# Adding data of one entity to other entity Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity named as Course and other as Tasks. To complete a course, user can create multiple Tasks. Now i have a screen with UITextFields that takes Course data and store it. User can create multiple courses and see them in a tableview.

Now, if the user selects a course, he will get the course detail fetched from the coredata, but at the same time he can also add a task in that course.

So what my issue is : How do i know that the task that is being saved has to be linked to that particular course that the user has selected.

Screenshot of DB Attached:
[image: Tasks]
[image: Coursework]

Comment if i am not clear.

This is what i am trying to do in CoreDataHandler.swift file

```
  class func saveTask(courseWorkName : CourseWork, taskName:String, percentComplete:Int, startDate:Date, endDate: Date, notes: String) -> Bool {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tasks", in: context)
    let task = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CourseWork", in: context)
    let courseWork = NSManagedObject(entity: entity1!, insertInto: context)


  //  task.setValue(entity1, forKey: "courseworkName")
    task.setValue(taskName, forKey: "taskName")
    task.setValue(percentComplete, forKey: "moduleName")
    task.setValue(notes, forKey: "notes")
    task.setValue(startDate, forKey: "startDate")
    task.setValue(endDate, forKey: "dueDate")
    task.setValue(courseWorkName, forKey: "courseWork")


    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    }catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to create a Relationship between both the entities. Can you share your DB design in core data @Keshu Rai

Comment: i have created. yes let me attach the screeshot

Comment: You use a relationship field in your `Task` and set the relevant `Course` instance as its value.  Your model should also have the one-to-many inverse relationship between `Course` and `Task`

Comment: Please go through the screenshot.

Comment: Simply say something like `newTask.courseWork = currentCourse`

Comment: thats the issue. how do i get what is currentCourse.

Comment: They selected it from the table view, so pass it to your next view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your courseWork Object to next pushed controller and access it.

At the time of Entering data into table do it like:

```
objCourse.tasks.append(task)
task.courseWork = objCourse
```

By doing this you could achieve inverse relationship. Using this you can access course using task and vice versa.

Access it like:

```
objCourseWork.tasks
objTask.courseWork
```

Comment: @Keshu Rai let me know if you need more clarity

Comment: Thanks @Dheeraj . I created an object of coursework to AddTaskVC and then i passed it as a parameter in SaveTask function. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your relations in your model already defined like below, you only have to set the course property of the task to the course object it should be related with.

[image]

Have fun.